# Computing matrix elements using Wigner-Eckart Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, representation-theory, wigner-eckart

I am trying to compute the matrix elements
\begin{equation}
\langle j \, m | a_{1}^{+} | j' \, m'\rangle
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\langle j \, m | a_{2}^{+} | j' \, m'\rangle
\end{equation}
using [Wigner–Eckart theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem)
. I started by defining Schwinger representation angular momentum as following
\begin{equation}
J^{a} = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta=1}^2 a_{\alpha}^{+} \sigma^{a}_{\alpha \beta} a_{\beta}
\end{equation}
I am having the trouble in incorporating the following statement to operators $a_{1}^{+}$ and $a_{2}^{+}$
\begin{equation}
    \langle j \, m | T^{(k)}_q | j' \, m'\rangle
  = \langle j' \, m' \, k \, q | j \, m \rangle \langle j \| T^{(k)} \| j'\rangle,
\end{equation}
I have found $| j \, m\rangle$ in terms of $a_{1}^{+}$ and $a_{2}^{+}$ and it is as following,
\begin{equation}
    | j \, m\rangle
  = \frac{(a_{1}^{+})^{j+m}(a_{2}^{+})^{j-m}}{\sqrt{(j-m)!(j+m)!}}| 0\rangle,
\end{equation}

Comment: Well... start by identifying $k$.  Next you will need to construct the $\vert jm\rangle$  in terms of $a_i^\dagger$'s to be able to compute the matrix element of any one component and thus extract the reduced matrix element.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have found|jm⟩ in terms of $a_{1}^{+}$ and $a_{2}^{+}$ and updated the question accordingly but I got struck while calculating matrix element of any one component.

Comment: well if you're going to compute the matrix element of a tensor operator of rank $k$ you need to find $k$...